# PayPal: Alternative to PayPal's Developer Account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I was using Paypal Sandbox for testing transactions last year using my [PayPal developer account.](https://developer.paypal.com)

I just checked last week that I cannot access my old account, so I decided to sign up for a new account. However, you need now to sign up for a business account. Business account is only available to U.S. businesses (I came from outside the US).

[image: Paypal - Developer Sign Up Form]

I was hoping if you can suggest an alternative and free developer account (similar to PayPal), but with a different payment gateway.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question, nonetheless i'm suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Integrating PayPal APIs is absolutely a programming task and creating an account is the mandatory initial step. I'm tired of finding PayPal questions being downvoted or closed just because they don't include a fiddle. This site is not only about source code and this question fully complies with the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *«if your question generally covers […] practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession […] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!»*.

Answer (score 3):

How about stripe ?

### [Stripe](https://stripe.com)

- Uses a JavaScript based API to complete transactions.
- Simpler to integrate with multiple platforms.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a US Business account to use developer.paypal.com.
Simply sign up via https://www.paypal.com/ for a live PayPal account, either Premier or Business, and you'll be able to log in to developer.paypal.com with it.

Note however that the [new REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) is currently available for live US Business accounts only, but this won't affect the availability of other Sandbox products or functionality.

I'll look into why the messaging states that you do, because that's not correct. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Do I still need to wait for the confirmation of the validity of my mailing address based from the credit card that I added?

Comment: If you added a credit card, yes. You don't have to add a credit card though.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert: Does every customer that we create a Web based Paypal Checkin app for, need to go and register a developer's account to get their application ID details, or can we do it on their be-halve, without needing access to their Business merchant account?